# 2-day and 3-day VWAP in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to determine a way to create a 2-day and 3-day VWAP, so that the anchor point would be the beginning of the prior session, and the beginning of two sessions ago, respectively. How can I accomplish this?

Right now it seems I could check `session.isfirstbar` and add `time + 86400000` to it? But then at the beginning of the next session it would reset since `session.isfirstbar` is true again.

Any ideas?